# Why does my thinkpad log in automatically if I lock my screen, shut my lid and then reopen it?

Tags: suspend, laptop, 15.10, lightdm, lock-screen

I've noticed some strange behaviour while working today. If I lock my screen with `ctrl`+`alt`+`l` it takes me to the login screen. If I then decide to shut my laptop it suspends correctly. But when I reopen my laptop it resumes, but the screen is not locked. It just takes me back to my desktop without me needing to enter my password, even though it was locked before it suspended.

Is this a bug? Is it normal behaviour? Is there a setting somewhere I can change so that upon resuming it displays the lock screen?

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 with lightdm 1.16.6 and unity 7.3.2. My power settings are set so that when the lid is closed it suspends.

UPDATE: this appears to be a bug, possibly related to gnome-screensaver. I have submitted a bug report on launchpad that can be viewed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1539206).

Comment: Does it work correctly if you shut the lid _before_ locking?

Comment: No, there is no difference. There is a slight flash of my desktop (the windows disappear for a second), but then everything is fine - no need to type my password.